# Picking rows from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

Let's consider the following list

```
data = {{1}, {}, {1,1,1}, {1,1}, {1}, {1,1}, {1}, {2,1,1}, {3,1}, {3,2,1}, {}}
```

As we can see, some rows have 0, other 1, other 2, etc elements. How can I pick only those rows which contain three elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select[Length@ # == 3&] @ data
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 1}}

Also

```
Cases[{_,_,_}] @ data

Cases[_?(Length @ # == 3&)] @ data

Pick[data, 3 - Length /@ data, 0]

Pick[data, Unitize[Length /@ data -3], 0]
```